# What can cause error code 32 followed by error code 2?

Tags: windows, smb

We are seeing this sequence of error codes as a recurring pattern in our filesystem retry logging in one customer network:

```
2021-01-12 17:33:18  INFO   Retrying CreateFile (...) after error code 32
2021-01-12 17:33:18  INFO   Retrying CreateFile (...) after error code 32
2021-01-12 17:33:18  INFO   Retrying CreateFile (...) after error code 32
2021-01-12 17:33:18  ERROR  CreateFile (...) failed with error code 2
```

Any idea how this sequence ("Sharing violation" followed by "File not found") could be explained?

Comment: Not much of any context.  Where is this log from?  Is this a log from an application? Could it be the Antivirus?   Could it be that the file that's being created is already opened?

Comment: This is from an application log. I cannot exclude any of your suggestions, but I don't understand the sequence of error codes. The file **does** exist with a creation date before the errors, so the error code 2 makes no sense for me.

Comment: Report the issue alongside the log to the application vendor. We cannot solve an issue caused by unknown code from a log excerpt written by unknown code following unknown policies.

Comment: Well, the question is about a specific sequence of Windows error codes when calling `CreateFile`...I was hoping for someone having experienced this before.

Comment: The sequence of events just reflects the choice of some undisclosed piece of software to solve some undisclosed problem. We do not know any more than you do.

Comment: You misunderstood. This is **our** software and all we are doing is calling  `CreateFile` for the same file in a retry loop.